# mysql in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

hi i'm new in docker and for practice created this project but when it's run with docker compose shows me below error:

```
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'user1'@'172.19.0.4' (using password: NO)
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3.9'

services: 
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mjs
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wpdb
      MYSQL_USER: user1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mjs

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment: 
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wpdb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user1
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWROD: mjs
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on: 
      - db

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 3333:80
    environment: 
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mjs
```

*I searched for stackoverflow but found nothing.*

Thank you for your help

Comment: `WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD` should have the `O` before the `R`.  Is this spelled correctly in your local file?  Misspelling it could cause Wordpress to attempt connecting without a password (which you see in the diagnostic you quote).

Comment: Thank you for your attention and guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not defining your db volume data is not persisting on restart. Just btw.
Furthermore it's a good practice to pin your image to a version like mysql:5.7.
Did you try that one here?
https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/